# Is AstroTurf really the opposite of Grassroots for movements?

Tags: meaning-in-context, antonyms

This [FOX & friends (@foxandfriends)](https://twitter.com/foxandfriends/status/828570204670091264/video/1) twitter post has a video with the following text (and quote):

> SPICER: Protesting has become a profession now. This has become a very paid **AstroTurf-type** movement

**AstroTurf** here is obviously used as the antonym to [grassroots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grassroots) which wikipedia defines as:

> A grassroots movement (often referenced in the context of a political movement) is one which uses the people in a given district as the basis for a political or economic movement.

Is AstroTurf really the opposite of Grassroots for movements?

Comment: There can be many "opposites" of something. Whether *astroturf* is an opposite here, let alone **the** opposite here, is primarily opinion-based.

Comment: 'really an opposite'? It's used as a _synonym_ with a difference, meaning not naturally formed like grass but fake as in paid for.

Answer (score 4):

No, it means something that looks like a grassroots movement but is, instead, a sponsored one.

> #### [Astroturfing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grassroots)
>
> - The practice of masking the sponsors of a message or organization (e.g., political, advertising, religious or public relations) to make it appear as though it originates from and is supported by a grassroots participant(s). It is a practice intended to give the statements or organizations credibility by withholding information about the source's financial connection.

The *AstroTurf* usage stems from the concept that normal *AstroTurf* mimics regular grass. Likewise, **Astroturf** pretends to be a **grassroots** movement.

Comment: +1 though perhaps it would be clearer with a mention of something closer to an antonym for contrast.